# how to change standard URL in codeigniter for multilanguage?

Tags: codeigniter, url, uri

I have a multi language website in code igniter with uses prefix in the URL to define the language. Works great but there is a problem when going to the home page.

The default URL is 
`localhost:8888` 
but it should be 
`localhost:8888/index.php/EN/welcome`

I tried redirecting in the controller but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must create a .htaccess file in your root path. File content like this;

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can edit your route file like this;

```
$route['(:any)/(:any'] = 'IndexController/getPage/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'IndexController/index/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'IndexController';
```

Route 1: Your sub page. First parameter is language, second parameter is page url

Route 2: Your home page. Parameter is language.

Route 3: Default home page in your main language.